# React - fetching data in useEffect, setting state with successful response, but losing data upon mysterious render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, vite

[screenshot of console log displaying data being lost][https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ieeTPV2031CxvG_fx6lIN-rbd2CvVzRR/view?usp=drive_link]

I am fetching data from google Sheets which I am successfully retrieving within a useEffect in PageContent.jsx. I am then setting the state of artistNamesArray to the response I fetch, which I then pass as a prop to a child component. However, the state of artistNamesArray is getting reset at some point, which causes the child prop to not have that data. I am still new to react and trying to better understand how all the re-rendering is occurring. Anyone have any idea why the state is being set back to an empty array? Also what would be a method to work around / fix this? See console log screenshot to display last console log displaying

PageContent component (parent):

```
const PageContent = () => {
  let allArtistNamesArr = [];
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    sheetData: [],
    artistNamesArray: [],
    // yearsArray: []
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      let response = await callGoogleSheets();
      setState({ ...state, sheetData: response });
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getAllBandNames = async () => {
      state.sheetData.forEach((artist) => {
        allArtistNamesArr.push(artist.Band);
      });

      let uniqueArtistNameSet = new Set(allArtistNamesArr);
      let uniqueArtistNameArr = Array.from(uniqueArtistNameSet);
      if (!state.artistNamesArray) 
      setState({ ...state, artistNamesArray: uniqueArtistNameArr });
    };

    getAllBandNames();
  }, [state.sheetData]);

  return (
    <section id="content">
      <div id="dataContainer">
        <BandsColumn
          bandNames={state.artistNamesArray}
          sheetData={state.sheetData}
        ></BandsColumn>
        <YearsColumn></YearsColumn>
        <ShowsColumn></ShowsColumn>
        <RecordingDetailsColumn></RecordingDetailsColumn>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};
```

BandsColumn component (child):

```
const BandsColumn = ({ bandNames, sheetData }) => {
    const [state,setState] = useState({
        allBandNames: []
    })

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("bandNames: " + bandNames)
  }, [bandNames]);

  const getSpecificArtist = (event) => {
    let specificArtistArray = []
    let clickedArtist = event.target.textContent
    
    sheetData.forEach((artist) => {
        if (clickedArtist === artist.Band) {
            specificArtistArray.push(artist)
        }
    })
    console.log(specificArtistArray)
    
  }

  return (
    <aside id="bandContainer">
      <h1>Bands: </h1>
      <ul>
        {state.allBandNames.length && state.allBandNames.map((name, index) => (
          <li key={index}>
            <a onClick={getSpecificArtist}>{name}</a>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </aside>
  );
};
```